# Show more button , div id with variable

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, html

I'm making a small script with show more button at the last of showing 10 entries. 
This is the code

```
<div id="more<?=$lastid;?>">
   <a onclick="showmore(<?=$lastid;?>);">More</a>
</div>
```

and the script is

```
function showmore(lastid) {

    $.post("/ajax/showmore.php", {
        lastid: lastid,

    }, function(response) {
        $("#more" + lastid).show();
        setTimeout("finishAjax('more' + lastid, '" + escape(response) + "')", 300);
    });

    return false;
}

function finishAjax(a, b) {
    $("#" + a).html(unescape(b));
    $("#" + a).fadeIn(1e3)
}​
```

but the script doesn't work ? what is the problem here ?

I tested the script with a constant div id and it run good but when I added the $lastid for the div and $("#more" + lastid) on the script side it doesn't work

any idea to make the DIV ID changeable ?

thanks in advance

Comment: If $lastid is a string and not a number, you'll need to wrap it in quotes or else the javascript will break: <a onclick="showmore('<?=$lastid;?>')">More</a>

Comment: it is a number !! but I think I will try your idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You All

I found the error

it was in this line

```
            setTimeout("finishAjax('more' + lastid, '"+escape(response)+"')", 300);
```

I correct it to

```
            setTimeout("finishAjax('more"+lastid+"', '"+escape(response)+"')", 300);
```

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1):

instead of appending the id to more which is kind of ugly, why dont you give the div a class "more"

```
  <div id="<?=$lastid;?>" class="more">
       <a onclick="showmore(<?=$lastid;?>);" >More</a>
  </div>
```

then your jquery selector can be this:

```
 $("div.more#" + id).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You reference lastid within the string for setTimeout(). You should use closures to solve this problem. However here is a clean version:

```
function showmore(lastid) {
    $.post("/ajax/showmore.php",
        { lastid:lastid },
        resultHandler);

    return false;

    function resultHandler(response) {
        $("#more" + lastid).html(response).fadeIn(1e3);
    }
}
```